# Node.js - Can I do a post but then not have to redirect or refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm working on creating a forum, and I'm pretty new to Node, but I have the basics working (search, create, reply, etc..). But when I make a reply I have it redirect to the current page basically refreshing it, And so I'm wondering if theres a way I can do it that wont refresh the page. Heres my code that works with the redirect, I know its probably not the best so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
router.route('/forum/:id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var owner = "UserName"
    var date = new Date().toISOString();
    var comment = req.query.comment
    var pushon = {owner: owner, date: date, reply: comment} 

    mongoose.model('Post').findByIdAndUpdate( req.id,
      {$push : {"replies" : { "$each": [pushon], "$position": 0 } }},
      {safe: true, upsert: true},
      function(err, model) {
        console.log(model);
      }
    );
    res.format({
      //HTML returns back to the main page
      html: function(){
        // Refreshes the page. anyway I can avoid that? And just have it update the info and display it?
        res.redirect("/main/forum");
      },
      json: function(){
        res.json({message : 'comment made',

         });
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're looking for AJAX. It's a client-side concept.

Comment: To expand on Madara's comment - a client would use javascript to hit the url instead, and then can modify window.location.href if it wants to redirect, or can manipulate the dom, adjusting it to show if a comment was made, etc. 

you are very fortunate in that you use node.js here, google around for isomorphic web applications and look into how you can share the same rendering logic for the backend with the frontend.